# Can I make a div not "solid" to the page window?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have the div on the left holding the "wing" that has a float left applied to it but what I need is that the middle div (there is one containing div2and3) to always be centered which I can do but if the width of the window is to small it pushes the mid container off screen because the left div locks on the edge.

I need that left div to not be "solid" so that it can be off the screen and not affect the auto margins on the middle div. Anyone? If you need more explanation I can onlytalk for another 20 minutes (im in class) and my internet was out last night/this morning we will see when I get home if its up.

(ignore my aquarium in the background it was the project we just did in this class)

Screencap:

[image: http://i53.tinypic.com/2lu3oz9.png]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Banta - Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(images/backgroundd.png);
}
body,td,th {
    color: #0d2927;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="maincont">
<div id="middlecont">
<div id="leftwing">
</div>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="body">
Lorem ipsum doler sit AMETTTTTTTTTTTTTTT FILLER TEXT FILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXTFILLER TEXT
</div>

</div>
<div id="rightwing">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#maincont {
    margin:auto;
    width:1518px;
    height:782px;
}

#leftwing{
    min-width:0%;
    background-image:url(images/leftside.png);
    width:405px;
    height:449px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-405px;
}

#rightwing{
    float:right;
    background-image:url(images/rightside.png);
    width:405px;
    height:449px;
    margin-top:-782px;
}

#middlecont{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    width:708px;
    height:782px;
}

#header{
    background-image:url(images/headhome.png);
    width:708px;
    height:150px;
}

#body{
    background-image:url(images/bodybg1.png);
    width:708px;
    height:632px;
}
```

Comment: Can you state your question explicitly in a sentence or two?

Comment: Where do you want the left div to go as the screen shrinks? Do you want it to collapse? You could use a min-width on it. It would help a lot if you provided some code with the base structure of your divs.

Comment: Basically yes, I want the left "wing" to collapse and hide the image gradually as the view-port is reduced. Here is the code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works -- I tested it in Chrome, IE8, FF 4.

The left "wing" is still solid (fixed width), but the absolute positioning means it doesn't affect the centering of the middle div. It will politely move off-stage to the left, gradually, as the view-port's width is reduced.

Place div1 *inside* middleDiv, and use absolute positioning -- you must apply {position:relative} to the middle div.

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
    div{outline:1px solid gray;}
    #div1{position:absolute;height:300px;width:100px;left:-100px;}  /*the value of the left property should be negative the value of the div's width */
    #div2, #div3{height:200px}
    #middleDiv{width:300px;margin:auto;position:relative;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="middleDiv">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Note: outline won't work in IE7 or less, it's just here to show the location of the divs.)

Comment: I was really hoping this would work but I still get the same problem when collapsing the page, the left "wing" does not move off to the left.

Comment: Not  sure why it's not working for you. You can see it work at http://jsfiddle.net/aDZEq/ . I'm sorry I didn't use the markup in your code sample, but I was going off the graphic you provided, which doesn't use the same name for divs, so I couldn't tell what each of your in-markup divs was intended for.

Comment: Oh I fixed it, the problem was the container I had around all of the divs, once I removed that it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fixed width `div2and3`, you can add a `min-width` style to your page's `body` element. Make the value to combined widths of all your elements (width of `div1` + width of `div2and3`).

Answer (score 0):

Does the left (div1) contain any information like a sidebar?  If all you want is a centered div, and div1 and div3 contain no information, do:

```
<div align="center">
  <div style="width: 80%" />  <!-- set your own percentage -->
</div>
```

Or just specify a width for div2 and leave the width alone for div1 and div1 should collapse when the width of the browser gets collapsed.